# React-native ImageBackground: image is not positioned at the same place depending of the resize mode

Tags: css, react-native, tabs, background-image, native-base

I would like to use tabs (from native-base) with a fixed background image. I have set a `BackgroundImage` that wrap the `Tab` and `Tabs` elements.

The code is:

```
 <ImageBackground style={{height: "100%"}} source={backgroundImage} resizeMode={'contain'}>
   <Tabs style={{height: "100%"}} page={this.state.page}>
        <TransparentTab>
            <ProfilPersonality />
        </TransparentTab>

        <TransparentTab>
            <Softskill />
        </TransparentTab>

        <TransparentTab>
            <RestitCards />
        </TransparentTab>
    </Tabs>
</ImageBackground>
```

This code is not doing what I want since the image background is not at the top of the screen, I tried to put an `absolute` position with `top: 0` but it does not change anything. Here is a **screenshot showing the wrong position**:
[image]

If I change the `resizeMode` from contain to repeat (without changing anything else) then the image is correctly positioned. Here is the **screenshot of the correctly positioned image but that repeats**:

[image]

**Why is there this behavior and how can the image be positioned at the top without being repeated?**

Answer (score 1):

Inset of setting the height to `100%` you can try setting the with to '100%' and the aspectRatio to that of the image. That should give you the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is what I tried at first, it does put the image where I want it to, but the content is cut if it is longer than the height of the image